# Как спарсить данные с одинаковыми классами

Tags: python, bs4

Помогите пожалуйста решить вопрос новичку. Необходимо спарсить данные с одинаковыми классами. Пробовал через Find(), но выдается результат только первого подобно класса class="section__info. Мне же необходим результат "Место нахождения". Буду очень признателен если подскажете как привязать содержание изменяющегося элемента адреса к постоянному элементу "Место нахождения".   Язык программирования Pyhton, модуль BeautifulSoup.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Через xpath можешь сделать

Comment: Какой модуль используешь?

Comment: Каким языком программирования работаешь? измени вопрос. Дай немного подробной информации.

Comment: Язык программирования Pyhton, модуль BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Используй .find_all()

Comment: Вопрос в том, как из всех class_=section_info выбрать именно конкретный адрес?

Comment: print(list(soup.stripped_strings)[2])

Answer (score 0):

Можешь использовать метод из bs4 - `find_all()` и получить нужное значение по  индексу, но также можно применить поиск по тексту с помощью регулярных выражений:

```
import re
import requests

url = "какой-то url"
markup = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeatifulSoup(markup, "lxml")

location_title = soup.find(class_="section_title", string=re.compile("Место нахождения"))
```

Дальше с помощью метода `find_next_sibling()` можно получить значение из места нахождения:

```
location = location_title.find_next_sibling().text
```